# IF / ELSE comparison with js variable

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, comparison

I'm trying to run the following code but surely missing something.
Regardless the value of the "myPlan" js variable the php echo is always "Something went wrong with the chosenPlan"

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<b>JAVASCRIPT</b><br>");
    var myPlan = sessionStorage.getItem("plan");
</script>
<?php
    $myPlan = '<script>document.write(myPlan);</script>';

    if($myPlan == 'plan1'){
        echo "Chosen plan is number 1<br>";
    } elseif($myPlan == 'plan2'){
        echo "Chosen plan is number 2<br>";
    } elseif($myPlan == 'plan3'){
        echo "Chosen plan is number 3<br>";
    } else {
        echo "-- Someting went wrong with the chosenPlan --";
    }
?>
```

Comment: just modified it. the php variable was not in the original post.

Comment: PHP and JS can't interact like that as one works on the server-side and one is client-side. You have to call the PHP code somehow, passing in your JS variable

Comment: can you explain a bit more ? Thank you.

Comment: Read the question that this has been marked as a duplicate of, there's a very good and detailed answer there

Answer (score 0):

$myPlan may be undefined and hence goes into else part. May be a good idea to check the value of $myPlan that you are getting.

Comment: this should be a comment, it doesn't answer the question

Comment: that's what I do in my original code (this one is just a snippet).
when I do the echo of $myPlan it suits to what I've chosen in the previous form. but still it goes into else part. I don't understand what I'm missing...